# Retrieve Information BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi everybody in a previous post ( [ListCollections with autorizedcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65107334/listcollections-with-autorizedcollection) ) I asked how to retrieve the name of the collections available in MongoDb'database. Finally the solution is much easier as expected and is :

```
            var db = mongoUser.GetDatabase(databaseName);
           
            var command = new CommandDocument { { "listCollections", 1 }, { "authorizedCollections", true },  {"nameOnly", true }};
            var result = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```

the problem is I am not used to work with BsonDocument. I could cast the "result" into a BsonDocument or onto a string and then cut until I found the name of the solution. But it is the wrong way. Could someone help me for this case ?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478613/how-to-deserialize-a-bsondocument-object-back-to-class

Comment: Someone gived the response here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338948/c-sharp-mongo-driver-imongodatabase-runcommand-to-get-database-stats

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `CommandDocument` since it's a Legacy API and you use not legacy code path in all other places. I think `BsonDocument` is the expected way to work with `RunCommand`. You can play with the above Deserialization suggestions but this will be just a step after `RunCommand`.
So I would expect something like this:

```
  var command = new BsonDocument { { "listCollections", 1 }, { "authorizedCollections", true }, { "nameOnly", true } };
  var result = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
  // any steps you want to process result including possible deserialization into typed view
```